# If span display set to inline do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a .net website that validates an input and if it fails adds an inline style 
"display:inline;"

Im trying to use jQuery to see this style and add a class to the respective input field.

```
if(!!$('span.errorp').length ){
   alert('hi');
}
```

the above is what im currently using to ensure i can target the correct tag which works,

I guess i need something similar too...

```
if(!!$('span.errorp').display:inline ){
    alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: If you have any control over the server-side code, change it -- adding an inline style is not the way to go. Then you won't have to correct it after the fact on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
if ($('span.errorp').css('display') === 'inline') {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
$('span.errorp').css('display', 'inline');
```

It's not necessary to check for length. If there are no matches, nothing happens.

Comment: Uhm, would'nt that just set the display style to inline, and not check to see if actually is inline?

Comment: Well, I guess I misunderstood the question. The syntax is all wrong!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('span.errorp[style=display:inline]')) {
    // do stuff
}
```